# Can anyone tell me what this pipe is?

Tags: pipe, gas

I was touring a property for sale and I saw this pipe sticking about 4 feet straight out of the ground. We asked the owner about it and she didn’t know.

Does anyone have any idea what it is?

[image]

Comment: It looks like an old yard water hydrant, or possibly  water hand pump, that has been taken apart.

Comment: If there is a hole on the top, would say it missing the pump handle.

Comment: What is the diameter of the pipe? It is difficult to tell was there a T at groundlevel? In my area som older farms have surface water pumps and there are hand pumps to prime them. Quite possible in areas with lots of creeks and lakes on vally floors

Comment: I'm with @AlaskaMan that it's what remains of a yard hydrant/hand pump. What does the writing on the "head" of the pump say?